# How can I convert a linux swap partition to ntfs?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, swap

Recently I decided to remove Ubuntu from my dual boot configuration of Windows and Ubuntu. I formatted the drive which contained Ubuntu, but I couldn't format my swap partition from Windows because it doesn't support it. How can I convert the swap partition to ntfs?

Comment: Why not just remove it in Windows and add the space to some partition?

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and the people here are very good at dual-booting and removing Windows, but not very good at getting it back once it was removed...  However, on http://superuser.com, a sister site to Ask Ubuntu, they're very good at deleting Ubuntu and installing Windows, so you might be better off there.  **;-)**

Comment: @Pilot6: sometimes Windows does not show partitions and space that does not have a well-known partition ID. As far as I can remember the swap space will not shown up in the partition administration.

Answer (score 0):

Use a linux live CD/DVD/USB and run gparted to recover your partitions.
You can try your ubuntu installation image or some specialized
distribution like [gparted-live](http://gparted.org/livecd.php/). Using this you need to delete the swap partition or you change the format to NTFS.

Comment: Please [edit] your answers, not add another answer.